# Get text from spans with same class

Tags: jquery

I've 5 spans, could be more, all share the class `.price`.

Reading documentation of Jquery, I find that the best approache is to use `map` function. Like this:

```
var prices = $(".price")
             .map(function () {
               return this.text;
             }).get().join();
```

> I need a list of prices, So afterwards I can do something like (notice
>   the minus 20 part):

```
$('.price').text(function (index) {
                            return "S/ " + prices[index]-20;
                        });
```

But when I alert `prices` I get an empty window.

**html**:

```
<span class="price price_50">50</span>
<span class="price price_100">90</span>
<span class="price price_200">120</span>
<span class="price price_300">140</span>
<span class="price price_500">150</span>
```

Comment: it's all emty spans

Comment: either you are reading it before the elements exist or before they have text..... right now they have no text in the example... dom also does not have .text

Comment: Are you trying to get the number from the `price_` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside map `this` refers to DOM and it doesn't have any `text` property. So convert it to jQuery object and get text content using `text()` method or get `textContent` property from the DOM object.

```js
var prices = $(".price")
  .map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
  }).get().join();

console.log(prices)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="price price_50">1</span>
<span class="price price_100">2</span>
<span class="price price_200">3</span>
<span class="price price_300">4</span>
<span class="price price_500">5</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla javascript uses `innerText`, which is what `text()` in jQuery references.

```js
var prices = $(".price")
  .map(function() {
    return this.innerText;
  }).get().join();

console.log(prices)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="price price_50">1</span>
<span class="price price_100">2</span>
<span class="price price_200">3</span>
<span class="price price_300">4</span>
<span class="price price_500">5</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some content inside each of your span.

```
<span class="price price_50">50</span>
<span class="price price_100">100</span>
<span class="price price_200">200</span>
<span class="price price_300">300</span>
<span class="price price_500">500</span>
<p id="list_price"></p>

 $( "p" )
  .append( $( ".price" ).map(function() {
       return $( this ).text();
        })
 .get()
 .join( ", " ) );
```